# IObservable - Replacing AutoResetEvent

Tags: .net, multithreading, system.reactive, autoresetevent

Just wondering how I can replace the AutoResetEvent in the below? I was trying to think how to do it the RX way or with tasks, but I can see how to do it.

```
public void LogOnResponse LogOn()
{

    LogOnResponse logOnResponse = null;
    var waitEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    var listener = _connection.LoginStatusEvent
                        .Where(x => x.LoginState == LoginState.LoggedOn 
                                    || x.LoginState == LoginState.LoggedRejected);

    listener.Subscribe(x => {
                            logOnResponse = new LogOnResponse();
                            logOnResponse.InformationMessage = x.Message;
                            logOnResponse.IsAuthenticated = x.LoginState == LoginState.LoggedOn;
                            waitEvent.Set();
                        });

    connection.Login(connectionInfo);

    waitEvent.WaitOne(2000);

    return logOnResponse;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider structuring the code like so:

```
var listener = _velocityConnection.LoginStatusEvent
    .Where(x => x.LoginState == LoginState.LoggedOn || x.LoginState == LoginState.LoggedRejected);

var logOnResponse = listener.Select(x =>
    new LogOnResponse() {
        logOnResponse.InformationMessage = x.Message;
        logOnResponse.IsAuthenticated = x.LoginState == LoginState.LoggedOn;
    }
).Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), Observable.Return(new LogOnResponse() {...}))
    .Publish()
    .RefCount();

connection.Login(connectionInfo);
return logOnResponse.First();
```

We use `Publish` to so that order of execution doesn't matter, and RefCount() to hide the `ConnectableObservable`

Comment: Would the "First()" need to come after login? Its just that the original IObservable will only start publishing results after login occurs... If I understand the code correctly it will block until it receives something but it never will because it hasn't logged in.

Comment: Also if this is the case what happens if the connection completes and publishes the notification through the notification before the First() method wires up?

Comment: Can you explain why .Publish() and .RefCount() are needed?

Comment: @vdh_ant Without the Publish/RefCount, the code is subject to race conditions; what if the Login finishes completely and publishes the status event before it gets to the Return?  That means the code blocks forever.

Comment: So does Publish() collect/cache the results so that if LoginStatusEvent pushes the data through the observable through before the First() is wired up the First still catches the event? If so is this similar to a ReplaySubject/BehaviorSubject Observable? Also not quite sure what you mean by "Hide the ConnectableObservable"...

Comment: @vdh_ant - yes. Yes, publish returns a ConnectableObservable, which uses a Subject. `RefCount` Takes a IConnectableObservable and returns a IObservable if "Returns an observable sequence that stays connected to the source as long as there is at least one subscription to the observable sequence. "

Answer (score 0):

I'd have the method return an `IObservable<LogOnResponse>` so you don't need to wait until your ready to return.  You'll also have to watch out for race conditions as your call to Login could complete before you have had a chance to subscribe. Something like this should handle the race conditions and give you back a response through the returned IObservable.  You can then obviously subscribe to this to get the LogOnResponse as soon as it turns up.

```
public IObservable<LogOnResponse> LogOn()
{
    return Observable.CreateWithDisposable<LogOnResponse>(observer =>
    {
       var loginDisposable = _velocityConnection.LoginStatusEvent
                        .Where(x => x.LoginState == LoginState.LoggedOn 
                                    || x.LoginState == LoginState.LoggedRejected)
                        .Select(x => {
                            logOnResponse = new LogOnResponse();
                            logOnResponse.InformationMessage = x.Message;
                            logOnResponse.IsAuthenticated = x.LoginState == LoginState.LoggedOn;
                            return logOnResponse;
                        }).Take(1).Subscribe(observer);

       connection.Login(connectionInfo);

       return loginDisposable;
   });
}
```

One thing to note here is that calling this method only returns the IObservable. The actual login won't be called until you subscribe.

```
// Gets the IObservable<LogOnResult>
var logonResponseAsObservable = LogOn(); 
//Execute the logon and wait for a response asynchronously
logonResponseAsObservable.Subscribe(response => HandleLogOnResponse(response));
```